# How to get some value of TD inside some TR with jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, checkbox, tablerow

i have a table in which every rows have a checkbox associated with the row ( same name ). So i want to let user to select one or more checkbox and delete it. The problem is that rows belong to two class of information. so i have row with classname `1` and rows with classname `2`. This is code i develope till now:

```
function delete() {
    // here i take all the checkbox checked
    var checked = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked");
    // the number of checkbox checked
    var nbChecked = checked.size();
    // just to the dialog
    var b = nbChecked == 1 ? "notification" : "notifications";
    if (confirm('Are you sure to delete [' + nbChecked + '] ' + b + "?\nTake care.. you cannot resume the action!")) {
        if (nbChecked > 1) {
            // i want to generate a matrix. every row has an array of information.
            var arr1;
            // i take this code on web, but it doesn't work. I want to pur in sent all 
            // the tr with class sent and with input checkbox associated with it checked.    
            var sent = $('.mainTable').find("tr.sent input[type=checkbox]:checked").get();
            //HERE i want to iterate array sent to take all the information of td inside it and pur in arr1.
            //HERE THE SAME DONE STILL NOW BUT CHANGING TR CLASS              
        } else {
            // HERE IS SIMPLE
        }
    }
}​
```

EDIT:
This one of the row with classname `sent`:

```
<TR valign=top name="rowSent1" style="background-color: #33CCCC" class="sent">
   <input type="hidden" value="messageRowSent1" name="message"/>
   <TD width=12>
      <div class="wpmd">
         <div align=center>
        <font color="#FF0000" class="ws7">
           <input type="checkbox" name="rowSent1" onchange="analizeCheckBox()"/> // onchange to check inputs checked
     </div>
      </div>
   </TD>
   <TD width=147 >
      <div class="wpmd">
         <div align=center>
        <font color="#000000" class="ws7"><I><div class="info1">info1</div></I></font>
     </div>
      </div>
   </TD>
   <TD width=156 >
      <div class="wpmd">
         <div align=center>
            <font color="#000000" class="ws7"><I><div class="info2">info2</div></I></font>
         </div>
      </div>
   </TD>
</TR>
```

Then i have other rows with the same class and other rows with another classname.

Can you help me? thanks!!!!

Comment: Can you post the HTML of your table.

Comment: of course! just a moment

Comment: in jquery i have only to get information to pass via post to a php page.. i want to pass the the matrix to a php page to iterate it and make the right query..

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan no ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I make this and it's work:

```
function getMatrix(type){
                var array;
               if(type=="sent"){
                  array = $("tr.sent input[type=checkbox]:checked").toArray()
               }else{
                  array = $("tr.period input[type=checkbox]:checked").toArray()
               }
                        var total = new Array();
                        for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++){
                            var tds = $(array[i]).parents("tr").children('td').toArray();
                            var mess = $(array[i]).parents("tr").children('input[type=hidden]').val();
                            var middle = new Array();
                            middle.push(mess);
                            for(var j=0;j<tds.length;j++){
                                var ii = $(tds[j]).text();
                                middle.push($.trim(ii));
                            }
                            total.push(middle);
                        }
                        return total;   
            }
```